# How to automatically detect links

Tags: javascript

Hello i am making a chat app in JavaScript and Firebase and i want when people mention their friends  etc.

to color only the @myname not the entire line

Its like this

User1 hello @test123 what are you doing?

to
↓ this to be like color green

User1 hello [@test123] what are you doing

can someone help me with this

Comment: Please show your effort so far you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions.

```js
const atMentionsRegex = /\@[^w]*/gi;
let message = "hello @test123 what are you doing?";
const atMentions = message.match(atMentionsRegex);
// ["@test123"] -> array of all mentions

const styledMention = (atMention) => {
    return `<span class="at-mention">${atMention}</span>`;
};

atMentions.forEach(atMention => {
    message = message.replace(atMention, styledMention(atMention));
});
```

Not the most efficient one but could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Define the dynamic content inside a div or a html tag assigning it with some class or id. then in javascript write the condition where the css of that particular id/class changes when the condition satisfies.